# IE 8 doesn't download html5shim and respond.js

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, respond.js

I have uploaded a page to a webserver. When I go there with IE and switch browser mode to IE 8 or IE 7 to see if html5shiv and respond.js are downloaded I see that they are not. Anybody knows why ? I use bootstrap's recommended template with a bit added code in a . Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <section>
      <h2>how are you doing ?</h2>
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my uploaded page is there http://toto3000.byethost24.com/bootstrap/basic%20ii.html

Comment: It is downloading from me. Checked in the network tab.

Comment: Yes it works. I was switching "browser mode" in IE rather than "document mode" that's why I couldn't see these files. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your first link by adding prefix (http://).

FROM: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
 TO : http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Your browser is trying to use a file protocole (file://)

Answer (score 0):

It works. I was switching "browser mode" in IE rather than "document mode" that's why I couldn't see these files. My bad.